# Get current location and city name Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, geolocation, location

I want to get the current location and city name using Xamarin.Android . I've used the code from this link https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/ but I only get 'Latitude' and 'Longitude'. Maybe I don't get the address cause I'm using an emulator ?

I want to fix this problem and get current location and address using the minimum code(using some plugin, api, maybe..)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at
[geocoder in android](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/geocoder/reverse_geocode_a_location/)

```
 var addresses = await geo.GetFromLocationAsync (42.37419, -71.120639, 1);
```

This recipe creates a Geocoder instance, which is in the Android.Locations namespace. The Geocoder calls GetFromLocationAsync with the latitude and longitude to reverse geocode. This will perform the network call asynchronously so that main UI thread is not blocked. When the result is returned, the method will return a list of addresses and continue on the UI thread. In this call 1 address is returned because that is the number passed into the third argument of the GetFromLocationAsync call. The returned address contains a variety of information about the location, including the street address.

Comment: I'm using geolocator  plugin in one project, and other project without using this plugin. I'm deploying both projects with Xamarin Android Player emulator, and I get Latitude and Longitude, but not the address.. Maybe I should install Google Play Services or something.. ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has a great tech article that works you through that entire process on Android using `Geocoder`.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

The code that does the Long/Lat to Address lookup is:

```
async Task<Address> ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation()
{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    IList<Address> addressList =
        await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

    Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
    return address;
}
```

FYI: Most emulators have a user-defined setting for mocking `Latitude` and `Longitude` so you can change it and test getting different responses.

i.e. In Xamarin's Android Player, there is a dialog of GPS settings:

[image]

There are similar setting in GenyMotion's Android Emulator, etc...

Comment: I'm using geolocator plugin in one project, and other project without using this plugin. I'm deploying both projects with Xamarin Android Player emulator, and I get Latitude and Longitude, but not the address.. Maybe I should install Google Play Services or something.. ?? Thanks in advance